# Can someone clarify me the differences between a Program and an Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

So, I have been doing a little research and searching around Google about Algorithms. I was getting the hang of it until I got a little deeper.

I understand that an **Algorithm is defined as:** a process or set of rules to be followed in calculations or other problem-solving operations, especially by a computer (Quoted from Dictionary). **A Computer Program is defined as:** is a sequence of instructions, written to perform a specified task on a computer (Quoted from Wikipedia)

An analogy I saw on a thread helped me a little bit:

Cake Algorithm:

```
--Get Ingredients
--Bake
--Serve
```

Cake Program:

```
--2fl of flour
--3 eggs
--Mix in pan
--etc.
```

As I saw the algorithm was more general

So basically how I began to think of a computer program was code that implements the Algorithm, in other words the Algorithm is a blueprint. For example, this is a simple Algorithm:

```
Step 1: Start
Step 2: Declare variables num1, num2 and sum. 
Step 3: Read values num1 and num2. 
Step 4: Add num1 and num2 and assign the result to sum.
    sum=num1+num2 
Step 5: Display sum 
Step 6: Stop
```

I am also aware after more google searches that Algorithms can be represented in pseudo-code:

```
if a>b 
    Display a is bigger than b #Simple Example, but you get the point
```

They can also be formed in real code (making the algorithm as you go) like this:

```
def foo():
    #Blank Code for Algorithm/to be used later
```

So now this is where my question comes in, a lot of stackoverflow threads I see ask a user to explain/correct their algorithm. However, when I look at the algorithm instead of seeing something like the above examples I will see this:

```
// I know this isn't Python but that's not the point!      
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {Console.Write('Hello World !');
}
```

No blank functions/empty code blocks, its all filled in and such
So now my questions:

1. Is the above code for example indeed an Algorithm? Or is it a program written that *follows* a Algorithm?
2. If it is considered an Algorithm, what is the difference between that being an Algorithm, and that code being a computer program?
3. If it is both, does that mean the two terms can be used interchangeably?

Any clarification to a beginner would be nice.

Comment: Simply put- A *program* is used to *implement* an *algorithm* or a *task*

Comment: I understand that part, but assuming you read the whole thing refer to the bottom and my first question.

Comment: no they are not interchangeable terms ... the above example is a program and an algorithm i guess ... for some loose definition of algorithm .... a computer program can be executed an algorithm is just a concept

Comment: He did answer your question. The algorithm is the form of the program, a set of abstract directions followed towards the completion of a task. The program contains the minutiae of implementation relevant towards the task completion for some arbitrary set of software and hardware. The terms are not interchangeable. I recommend you study this text: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html

Comment: "Program" is synonymous with "implementation", i.e. "code" is always a program as it's an implementation (realization) of an algorithm. An algorithm has no programming language, a program does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all welcome to StackOverflow and the world of coding.

The answers to your questions:

1.Is the above code for example indeed an Algorithm? Or is it a program written that follows a Algorithm?

```
The above code is a "program" . An algorithm is like you said the blueprint and the whole architecture itself.

The algorithm for the above code could be:

STEP 1: START
STEP 2: Print Hello World 5 times. (That's it actually)
STEP 3: END
```

**You see the algorithm is something which describes a code in simple plain language. You can explain the blueprint of a program in pseudo code or a flowchart. You can't feed it to the PC without actually giving it the form the PC will accept. Therefore You need to convert it into a program using languages like C ,CPP, Python etc**

2.If it is considered an Algorithm, what is the difference between that being an Algorithm, and that code being a computer program?

```
WELL that's is not the algorithm as described above. And the answer to remaining part is explained as above
```

3.If it is both, does that mean the two terms can be used interchangeably?

```
No, it shouldn't be because of the exact same reason stated above.
```

Hope You get it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
// I know this isn't Python but that's not the point!      
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  Console.Write('Hello World !');
}
```

> Is the above code for example indeed an Algorithm? Or is it a program
>   written that follows a Algorithm?

Nope. If you were to remove the *printing part* and just add `print hello world` instead of `Console.Write()`, it *could* be an algorithm to print hello world `N` times.

> If it is considered an Algorithm, what is the difference between that
>   being an Algorithm, and that code being a computer program?

An algorithm is language independent, it just shows *how to do something*, the language defines a stricter set of rules on *how to implement something*. A program is used to implement an algorithm considering the rules and syntax defined by a language .

> If it is both, does that mean the two terms can be used
>   interchangeably?

Nope. An algorithm is not *language specific* whereas a *program* is always used in conjunction with a *programming language*.

Sample statement : *Write a Java program to implement BubbleSort algorithm*.

Answer (score 0):

Same difference as between a class and an instance object.